# Will exception be thrown back if try catch is already present with only a specific catch?

Tags: java, exception

I have a java method as follows regarding exception throws

```
public void wrapException(String input) throws MyBusinessException {

        // do something   

}
```

MyBusinessException extends Exception class and returns any(every) exception to the caller. My doubt is,

Imagine my code is now changed to handle one specific exception in a special way as below.

```
public void wrapException(String input) throws MyBusinessException {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new MyBusinessException("there was a number error", e);
    }
}
```

Would the *throws* on the method signature still return any exception apart from NumberFormatException to the caller or would I have to redesign the methods as follows?

```
public void wrapException(String input) throws MyBusinessException {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new MyBusinessException("there was a number error", e);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
     throws MyBusinessException(e.message());
}
}
```

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Yes, and I believe this is discussed in detail in the documentation.

Comment: Only one catch will be handled iin your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first solution, it will just catch exceptions with type `NumberFormatException` and any class that inherits from it.

```
public void wrapException(String input) throws MyBusinessException {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new MyBusinessException("there was a number error", e);
    }
}
```

However in your later solution, since you have `catch(Exception e)` in your method body, your method will catch any exception that inherits from `Exception` class including your very own `MyBusinessException`. Hence, you don't have to put `throws MyBusinessException` in the method signature.

```
public void wrapException(String input) throws MyBusinessException {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new MyBusinessException("there was a number error", e);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
     throws MyBusinessException(e.message());
}
}
```

This is enough;

```
public void wrapException(String input) {
        try {
            // do something
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new MyBusinessException("there was a number error", e);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
         throws MyBusinessException(e.message());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that I can remove the _throws_. But my question was the other way around. Do I need to add another catch(Exception e) or is the _throws_ on the method signature sufficient to return all other exceptions to the caller apart from NumberFormatException (which is handled and thrown)?

Comment: throws on the method signature will return just MyBusiness exception. If you want to return all exceptions you need to add throws Exception on the method signature and remove the catch(Exception) in the method body

Answer (score 1):

First we need to understand "throws on the method signature still return any exception" throws never return or throw any exception, its only a declaration or a hint for compiler that this method can throw exception. This declaration is only needed when the method itself don't want to handle the exceptional scenario and the exception is "Checked". i.e. in case of "Checked" exception compiler enforce you to either handle it (using catch) or declare the exception using throws keyword. If we declare it using throws then the same enforcement will be applicable for the caller method. When any exception is thrown within a method and the exception is not caught in that method that is always thrown to the caller method.
i.e

```
int divideByZero(int n){
 return n/0;
}
```

will throw ArithmeticException even though we have not declared it with throws. (As this is "Unchecked" means Compiler doesn't enforce the declare or catch rules for "Unchecked" exceptions.)

So in your case second catch is not mandatory but a choice.

Comment: Will appreciate if you could confirm if second catch -
 catch ```catch(Exception e) {
         throws MyBusinessException(e.message());
    }```  is not necessary precisely _because I already have a throws MyBusinesException_ on the method signature (which would do the needful i.e alert the compliler to return any unchecked exception back to the caller.)

Answer (score 0):

`catch (NumberFormatException e)` will only catch `NumberFormatException` and any subclass of it.  It will not, for example, catch `IllegalArgumentException`.

If you want to handle other types of exceptions, you will have to catch them explicitly.